# Alignment in horizontal stack view of label and switch

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm trying to use a horizontal stack view inside of a vertical stack view to create a series of labels and switches for settings. I want the switches to line up vertically but their position changes based on the length of text in the label when have fill proportionally selected. Other choices either throw the switch all the way to the right margin or Fill Equally doesn't leave enough space for a longer label and too much white space to the right of the button.

Thanks

Comment: *"Other choices either throw the switch all the way to the right margin"* ... isn't that what you want? A "column" of labels on the left and a "column" of switches on the right?

Answer (score -1):

UIStackView are arranging its subviews depending on UIView's `intrinsicContentSize`

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
```

Don't forget, you should avoid changing this size on runtime.